# Two's complement subtraction

Tags: twos-complement

-5-8
Do we have to represent both integers in 2's complement form and then add?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `-5-8` is the same as `-5` + `-8`, so if you were to take two's complement and add, you would get the answer (`-13`).

Another way to look at it, which is a little bit less work, is to see that `-5` + `-8` is `-(5+8)`, so you could add `5+8` first, then take the two's complement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, but it's a correct solution, provided that the result will not overflow.

EDIT: By overflow I mean not fit in the representable range. For example in 4-bit arithmetic -8 is 1000, and -5 is 1011 (-8 + 3), so the result should be -13, but (1000 + 1011 = 10011), the leading 1 doesn't fit, and we get 3 istead of -13.

Comment: It's not the algorithm that causes the overflow; 4-bit signed integers are insufficient for the problem, irrespective of the algorithm.